# JButton show tooltip programically: actionMap.get("postTip") is null

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jbutton, focuslistener

I need to programically show tooltip for my button2 when it gets focus. (I press Tab as intially focus at button1)

```
            JButton button = new JButton("Button 1");

            JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
            button2.setToolTipText("tooltip2");
            button2.addFocusListener(new FocusListener());
```

I refer the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473464/forcing-a-java-tooltip-to-appear) by @camickr

```
private class FocusListener extends FocusAdapter {
 public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
 {
    JComponent component = (JComponent)e.getSource();
    Action toolTipAction = component.getActionMap().get("postTip");
```

but toolTipAction is set null.

I have printed all the entries of ActionMap using this code

```
        ActionMap actionMap = component.getActionMap();
        Object[] actionMapKeys = actionMap.allKeys();

        for (int i = 0; i < actionMapKeys.length; i++) {
            Object key = actionMapKeys[i];
            System.out.println(key.toString() + " : " + actionMap.get(key).toString());
        }
```

This is what it gives me

```
pressed : javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener$Actions@49cf9f
released : javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener$Actions@1de0b5e
```

**So how can I call this code if I got toolTipAction null?**

```
ActionEvent postTip = new ActionEvent(component, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "");
toolTipAction.actionPerformed(postTip);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> actuall I want to show tooltip on some network event, which has
>   nothing to do with mouse. but I have started experiments with focus
>   gained by Tab key

- use `JWindow` (undecorated `JDialog`) or `JLabel` instead of `ToolTip`, examples for `JLabel` [by @Guillaume Polet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715612/how-to-display-a-text-above-a-jtable-cell-when-editing/10716342#10716342) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5957405/714968)
- you can to lay this container to the `Mouse Cursor` possition or to stick to absolute coordinates, `Point` to the visible GUI
- standard could be (can be annoying) see [SystemTray and TrayIcon#displayMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707482/714968)

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov You can also take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822819/dynamically-update-tooltip-currently-displayed/12823177#12823177) where I automatically make a tooltip appear on a component although I don't have any actual MouseEvent (we dynamically create a fake one): `ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().mouseMoved(
                            new MouseEvent(component, -1, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, locationOnComponent.x, locationOnComponent.y,
                                    locationOnScreen.x, locationOnScreen.y, 0, false, 0));`

Answer (score 2):

You could also try alternative approach of configuring the tooltip manager to immediately show the tooltip when mouse is entered.

```
javax.swing.ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setInitialDelay(0)
```

If you want this to happen only for some components then you could change this value depending on the component that gets focus.

Tooltip is also shown when `Ctrl+F1` is pressed. So may be you could simulate a Ctrl+F1 using `java.awt.Robot` on the button when you want to display tooltip.

Comment: actuall I want to show tooltip on some network event, which has nothing to do with mouse. but I have started experiments with focus gained by Tab key